# Disabling a button in page editor (ribbon) for field-type image

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore, ribbon, page-editor

I have used a custom image component which has image field-type ribbon when editing in page editor.

In core db, there are 3 webedit buttons for image which I need to hide/disable:

path: **/sitecore/system/Field types/Simple Types/Image/WebEdit Buttons/**

buttons: 
 **1. Choose Image 
 2. Image Properties
 3. Clear Image**

Also, i am aware that this is possible by overriding **Querystate()** method but im unsure of its implementation as I am new to CommandState handling.

**Instead of going through QueryState** , I am trying this

I have set the property "**DisableEdit**" of image as:

```
<myImage:PictureFillImage Field="<%# MyImage.Constants.FieldNames.Image %>" DisableEdit="true" ID="UIImage" runat="server"/>
```

I am using a custom class as:

```
public class PictureFillImage : Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FieldControl
```

And i am trying to disable web editing for the image as:

```
    public bool DisableEdit { get; set; }


    private Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Image _smlImage;
    private Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField _smlImageField;
    private Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FieldControl _fieldControl;

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataBind();
    }

    public override void DataBind()
    {
        // base.OnLoad(e);
        this.Item = this.GetItem();

        if ((this.Item != null) && (this.Field != null))
        {
            Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field field = this.Item.Fields[this.Field];
            if (field != null)
            {
                this._smlImageField = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField)field;
                this._smlImage = new Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                this._smlImage.Field = this.Field;
                this._fieldControl = this._smlImage as Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FieldControl;
                this._smlImage.ID = this.ID;
                this._smlImage.CssClass = this.CssClass;
                this._smlImage.Parameters = "all=all";
                this._fieldControl.Item = this.Item;


                this._smlImage.DisableWebEditing = DisableEdit;
                this._fieldControl.DisableWebEditing = DisableEdit;
            }
        }

        base.DataBind();
    }
```

I was hoping that the code would hide the three buttons: "Choose Image", "Image Properties" and "Clear Image" that appear in the floating ribbon in the page editor but I had negative result.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the query state method and return hidden or enabled

```
 public override CommandState QueryState(CommandContext context)
 {
    // your logic here
     //access current item
     var item = context.Items[0];

    // return either Commandstate.Hidden or Commandstate.Enabled
 }
```

For each button you will have a command class declared so you can customize the behaviour for each button.

You can get access to the current item as well.

There's a good example here on how to overrride the querystate to affect the state of the buttons

https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2010/09/10/unlock-sitecore-items/

Comment: How do i get the only those 3 buttons to hide and not the others...Can u give me link that explains details about commandstate and querystate and their use..that would be great.. :-)

Comment: This would apply to each and every image type component which are having those three buttons....which is not what i need..

Comment: Arent these three buttons(choose image, image prop, clear image) the default web edit buttons for Sitecore image ?